# How can I set horizontal scrolling If split view size is exceed my screen size in mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am adding split views dynamically to my view controller. At some point added split view size is exceed the screen size but con't get any scrolling. I am adding scroll view to my view controller but con't get it. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code? I assume you are setting the orientation of the scrollview? ScrollView {Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal };

Comment: I will explain my scenario. I have create a view controller in story board and adding scroll view to that one. Inside scroll view I have added a vertical split view. Now I have try to add sub view's to that split view programatically but when split view size increased more than screen size not scrolling the screen.